# What data object allows limiting possible values in variable?

Tags: data-structures

I remember learning about certain best practices around this, but I blanked completely on the name of what this is called. Basically, instead of saying:

```
pencil_1.size = 'SHORT';
pencil_2.size = 'LONG';
pencil_3.size = 'SHORT';
pencil_4.size = 'SHORT';
pencil_5.size = 'MEDIUM';
```

We would say:

```
pencil_1.size = Length.SHORT;
pencil_2.size = Length.LONG;
pencil_3.size = Length.SHORT;
pencil_4.size = Length.SHORT;
pencil_5.size = Length.MEDIUM;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer: Enum. That's the term I was looking for.

Comment: An "enumeration" is one method found in several common languages, yes. Depending on the specific language, there are several concepts that can be used to limit type / value sets. Also, one can get "un-typed" restrictions by using containers or naming conventions: in the code in the question there is no guarantee that "Length" is a proper enumeration (as this depends on language/features) and it might simply *imply* a set of candidate / allowable set values.